# TLS1.2 AES 128 CBC Encrypted Data size

Tags: tls, cryptography, aes

I know that TLS ciphers such as `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` transmit data as [shown](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.2). From my understanding, the ciphertext *must* be a multiple of the block size, which in this case is 16 bytes. However, when I look at the below output from Wireshark, I'm confused.

After subtracting the 16 bytes corresponding to the IV from the beginning of the Encrypted Application Data, that leaves 100 bytes of ciphertext which is obviously *not* a multiple of 16. What am I not understanding?

**EDIT**: Based on the structure of the struct in the above link, I was under the impression that the MAC was appended to the plaintext prior to encryption and thus included in the ciphertext.

[image: Wireshark Output]

Answer (score 4):

The final `SHA` in `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` also means (among other things) that every packet has an HMAC-SHA-1 tag, to ensure the data has not been tampered with. This has length 20 bytes, as this is the digest length of SHA-1. So of the 116 bytes, the final 20 are this tag and we are left with 96 = 6 times 16 pure ciphertext (AES-CBC) bytes, the first 16 are the IV needed for the CBC mode, and there is some padding at the end but we have about 4 to 5 blocks of actual application data in here.

Comment: Only if both endpoints implement the option/extension for encrypt-then-mac rfc7366 which IME is rare. 'Basic' TLS does HMAC _before_ CBC-with-padding-to-blocksize.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Well, encrypt-then-mac seems the only explanation for the length we see. Maybe the OP could look at the handshake more closely.